# QT creator - how to achieve access to component from GUI creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am drop some `QLabel` on main form my qt gui app, and after that in my main class "mainwindow" I cant reach `label`? Why and how to solve it? (I am trying to type `label` - its name and there isn't any.)

Comment: Please elaborate on what you've tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forms created in designer are translated to C++ code by the uic (UI Compiler), and that creates a class in the Ui Namespace. Instantiate that class (if it's not already done), and access your label through it.

For example, if you created a form named FormName, then uic generated ui_FormName.h, include that in your mainwindow class, and add a member variable of type Ui::FormName (usually called ui), call ui.setupUi on this variable on your constructor, and ui.label is your label.

Comment: by **default** in Qt Creator you will be accessing it mostly by `ui->label`